# Resetting form with token field on alpaca.js

Tags: javascript, alpacajs

I have spent a couple of hours trying to figure out how to properly reset a form with token field on alpaca.js.

Not sure if this is a bug, or I am doing something wrong. I placed two reset buttons, a generic one and a second one that calls a function to reset the form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var value = {};
$("#myform").alpaca({
 "schema": {
    "title": "token field",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "text_field": {"type": "text" },
        "token_field": { "type": "token"},
    }                       
},
"options": {  
    "fields": {
            "text_field": {
                    "label": 'this is a text field', 
                    "type": "text"
            },
            "token_field": {
                    "label": 'this is a token field', 
                    "type": "token",
                            "tokenfield": {
                    },
            },
    },
    "form": { 
            "buttons": {
            "load": {
                    label:"load saved values",
                    "click": function() {
                            $('form#' + this.attributes.id)[0].reset();
                            this.setValue(value);
                    },      
            },
            "reset": {},
            "fancy_reset": {
                    "label": "reset with function",
                    "click": function() {
                            console.log(this.attributes.id);
                            $('form#' + this.attributes.id)[0].reset();
                    },
            },
            "save": {
                    label:"save",
                    "click":function(){
                            value = this.getValue();
                            console.log(this.getValue());
                            console.log(value);
                    },
            },
            },
    },
},
});
</script>
```

Any insights on whats wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with Alpaca for year but I haven't use that type of and after some research I haven't found any solution in the Alpaca lib to reset that type of field, so I tried to use jquery and [bootstrap tokenizer methods](http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/#methods).

and I've came to this solution :

1. Create an eventlistener to the reset form event

   ```
   $('form').on('reset', function(e) {
      var control = $("#myform").alpaca("get");
      var field = control.childrenByPropertyId['token_field'];
      field.refresh();
   });
   ```
2. In your `load` function after `this.setValue(value)` add this code:

   ```
   if (typeof value.token_field != undefined) {
     // getting Alpaca parent control (this holds everything)
     var control = $("#myform").alpaca("get");

     // get the token field 
     var field = control.childrenByPropertyId['token_field'];

     // setting the saved token to the field using bs-tokenizer method setTokens
     $(field.control).tokenfield('setTokens', value.token_field);
   }
   ```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/a471u5xq/) for that.
Tell me if you still have any issue.